# How to pass a jQuery variable to a plugin property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Sorry I'm beginner, can somebody help me out?

```
<script>
var iW = $(document).width();

$(function() {
//single book
$('#mybook').booklet({
   next: '#custom-next',                
    prev: '#custom-prev',
     keyboard: true,
    width:   return iW, // here is the problem! It doesn't work.
    height: 200

});

//multiple books with ID's
$('#mybook1, #mybook2').booklet();

//multiple books with a class
$('.mycustombooks').booklet();

});

</script>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is _not_ an error description.

Comment: @Tomalak: Quite true, @Max in general when you find yourself writing "it doesn't work," best to stop and write "I'm expecting ____, but instead ____ is happening." Although in this particular case, it's pretty easy to tell what the problem is...

Comment: @TJCrowder: Yea, it's not the best example but I though it likely worth mentioning as a general rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` there is unnecessary.  You just need `width: iW`.

That said, you should also bring the call to `$(document).width()` within the `ready` block.

```
$(function () {
    var iW = $(document).width();

    //single book
    $('#mybook').booklet({
        next: '#custom-next',
        prev: '#custom-prev',
        keyboard: true,
        width: iW,
        height: 200

    });

    //multiple books with ID's
    $('#mybook1, #mybook2').booklet();

    //multiple books with a class
    $('.mycustombooks').booklet();

});
```

Answer (score 5):

You're *really* close. Just ditch the `return`, e.g.:

```
$('#mybook').booklet({
   next: '#custom-next',                
    prev: '#custom-prev',
    keyboard: true,
    width:   iW, // <=== Updated
    height: 200

});
```

That will use the *value* of `iW` as of the time you call `booklet`.

Within an object literal (that's the `{ ... }`  thing that you're passing into the `booklet` function), property initializers are a lot like assignment statements. The bit on the left before the `:` gives the property name (and cannot be an expression), and the bit on the right after the `:` gives the *value* for the property (and **can** be an expression — a simple variable name, a function call, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

As above, you don't need the return.

But alternatively many plugins will accept functions for their parameters to evaluate when needed so you could e.g.

```
$('#mybook').booklet({
    next: '#custom-next',
    prev: '#custom-prev',
    keyboard: true,
    width: function() { return $(document).width(); },
    height: 200
});
```

I don't know that plugin so I'm not 100% sure it'll support it, but many do.